# Sending mail on a google server

Tags: php, email, google-cloud-console

One of my clients has a google server, I traditionally send email using some simple php mail code, now I have noticed that emails cannot be sent from a google server. I am aware that google block certain ports for spam purposes, so here is my question how would I proceed to send mail from a google server. What is the easiest solution. I am aware of mail api's that google suggests such as mailgun api. But I have no references or clue how to start.

So something simple like this wont work on a google server

```
// the message
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
mail("someone@example.com", "My subject", $msg);
```

Comment: mail function actually takes 4 parameters and check php.net for that

Comment: I realise that something like -  mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)

Comment: So search for mail headers and use it..

Comment: but thats not my question

Comment: SO CAN YOU EXPLAIN ???

Comment: read what i asked I said how come google servers dont allow sending mail from a google server, that code I used above was just to demonstrate what I was saying

Comment: I am not asking how to send a php mail, I just would like to know why does google block normal php emails sending and how to bypass or go around it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know